# Ubuntu does not work

Tags: interface

I have windows7, I download Ubuntu and then installed it from windows.
The installation completed successfully within approximately 2 hours.
I restarted my PC and selected Ubuntu rather than windows7, but Ubuntu does not work and only a black screen with a write cursor appears.
Note:
Version: ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386
What is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you remove Wubi if you used Wubi To Install Ubuntu, And The Follow The Guide Here To Install Recent Version of  Ubuntu Properly:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

To Keep Windows, Simply Click Install Alongside Windows And Split Your Partition.
If the option is not there, You Can Simply Partition It Using The Something Else Option Or By Clicking Try Ubuntu And Then Opening GParted.

Hope this Helped!

Comment: what do u mean by Wubi?

Comment: How did you install ubuntu? Was it using A Program Called Wubi? Uninstall Ubuntu, And Then Follow the guide i sent you

Comment: no, i download it as an ISO file then burn it on DVD
the install it

Comment: Then simply download the most recent one and reinstall ubuntu

Comment: If this answered the question, please close the thread

Comment: I saw that I used Wubi To Install Ubuntui, So I remove it then download it from link y gave me.
now, what can i do?

Comment: @Hawraa you will need a Burnable CD Or Usb, If you wanna use a CD, Click Here:http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows             If you wanna use a USB Click Here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows